# Why does omniauth-twitter work locally but not on my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I have a Rails 5 (Ruby 2.3.3) app with [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) (1.6.1; omniauth-oauth 1.1.0) and [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) (1.4.0).  When a user is directed to Twitter for the OAuth flow, they see the following error after tapping the "Authorize application" button:

> **Whoa there!**
>
> There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

The most unfortunate problem about this error is it doesn't happen locally—I have a an identically configured app in Twitter's app management console, save for a different URL (127.0.0.1 for the local app, a Heroku URL for the server).

Additionally, we have other OmniAuth strategies that work without issue locally and in production.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your system clock is set correctly and that all of your keys are entered correctly. Ensure you're using the right paths (api.twitter.com/oauth/*) and make sure that you're actually sending a request token to the oauth/authorize page and not an access token.

Comment: System clock is Heroku, so I hope it's set correctly (and that's all I can do).  I'm using the [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) gem, and verified that it is using the correct URL.  I think you're talking about an earlier stag in the process that is successful—the user gets sent to Twitter and clicks the "Authorize" button there.  It's after that when my app (via OmniAuth) requests an access token for the user (I think).